# How can i use "New Axes" on developer navigation in chart.js library?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm beginner about chart.js library, I were read document of library, but i even not understand using "New Axes", I were looking for about it but not yet, Can you give me some examples of "New Axes" of Chart.js with react js programing ? , thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you find a solution to solve it?

Comment: not yet find solution :(